# Ruby + Passenger - Redmine deployment issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, passenger, redmine

I am trying to deploy Redmine on my web server. 
I have chose to use passenger to deploy the ruby app.

I have tested with the rake's demo app, but when I pointed my VitualHost to the red mine public folder I got this error:

```
Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/redmine/public/
```

Can anyone help?

Virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName redmine.myserver.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public
      ErrorLog /var/www/redmine/redmine-error-log
      <Directory var/www/redmine/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Serverfault might better suits your demand I flagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue.
The problem was caused by SElinux.
I had to enable the permissive mode.

```
setenforce 0
```

Then I have configured the Redmine app and set the correct permissions to the folders again.
In the end I have disabled the permissive mode:

```
setenforce 1
```

Comment: What happens when you restart apache after setenforce 1 again? My guess is the same problem occur. If it permanently fixed it can you  please specify the permissions / SE linux config you have changed?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO Passenger is missing some configuration in your example. Here is what I've in production :

```
<Directory /var/www/redmine>
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

Where /var/www/redmine was created as a symbolic link :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/redmine/public /var/www/redmine
```

You might also ensure that the rights are properly set on your redmine folder (the root one).

Comment: I have configured my virtual host as described in the passenger's documentation.

Comment: I configured mine as suggested in a Redmine installation tutorial i've found and it works.

Comment: I have updated the httpd.conf and created the symlink and I still get the same error.

Comment: I installed it on Ubuntu 10.04 for myself but I had tough problem, that might not be linked with passenger, are you making the setup through the package maanger ?

Comment: I can run other ruby apps. Redmine is throwing this error. I am deploying on CentOS 6.2.

Comment: Yes, positive. I have a lead on a SElinux issue that might cause this issue. Any idea about specifics?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8181/discussion-between-aster-and-andrei)